# Windows Cannot automatically detect proxy settings

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, proxy, fedora-21

My Windows 8.1 desktop cannot connect to any internet services through Ethernet to my home network. I tried resetting my adapter, restarting, netsh resets, and everything else I could think of. I'm not sure what could be causing this error.

I know it is not my Ethernet cable, and I don't believe it is the router or modem, as other devices can connect just fine. I can access a chromecast and a NAS just fine.

It may be a hardware issue, as when I booted into Fedora 21, it still would not connect. My roomate recently just upgraded to a tm-ac1900 router, and that is around the time this occurred.

Below is the output of `ipconfig /all`.

Why am I having troubles connecting this machine to the internet?

---

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Thunderlane
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : T-mobile.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : SAMSUNG Mobile USB Remote NDIS Network De
vice
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-01-0A-00-31-37
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f85e:248f:5267:a56d%21(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.35(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, December 21, 2014 5:41:11 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, December 21, 2014 7:11:10 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352452874
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-E9-CC-68-74-D4-35-97-34-87

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : T-mobile.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-D4-35-97-34-87
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::75b0:b243:1ea4:254a%2(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.226(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, December 21, 2014 5:41:06 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, December 22, 2014 5:41:06 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 259314741
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-E9-CC-68-74-D4-35-97-34-87

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.T-mobile.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : T-mobile.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:84d:395a:3f57:d5dc(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::84d:395a:3f57:d5dc%15(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352321536
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-E9-CC-68-74-D4-35-97-34-87

   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{CB9E2B41-1C53-41C6-8781-35D6A0D24C86}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your question (the windows IP configuration) properly - almost unreadable

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to having **two Default Gateways** defined, one on each of your Ethernet adapters, but apparently only one of them has Internet access.

Solve this by:

1. Disabling one of your Ethernet adapters.
2. Check for Internet connectivity.  If it's restored, then either:

   - Leave that adapter disabled
   - Convert it to a static IP configuration *without* specifying a Default Gateway
3. If Internet connectivity isn't restored, re-enable the adapter, then start at step #1 by disabling the other adapter.

Comment: Actually, the second adapter was my phone, which I tethered over USB in order to post this. But now everything seems to be working again over my Ethernet, and I'm not sure why. If I find out why it righted itself, I'll post. I know it wasn't something I did, because it happened while my computer was locked and running a virus scan. Although it doesn't say it found anything.